# How to add styles to slides in Swiper Element in React

Tags: reactjs, styling, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper Element for React and I'm trying to add css styles to the swiper slides but it seems the styles are not being injected. The snippet below should demonstrate the problem. How do I fix this?
Swiper Version: 10.3.1

```
const MyComponent = ()=> {

   const swiperElRef = useRef<SwiperContainer | any>(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {

     if (!swiperElRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    // styles are not working
    const params = {
      injectStyles: [
        `
              .swiper-slide {
                width: auto;
                background: blue;
              }
          `,
      ],
    };

    Object.assign(swiperElRef.current, params);
    swiperElRef.current.initialize();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
     <swiper-container
          style={{ width: "100%", paddingBlock: "1rem" }}
          spaceBetween={16}
          slidesPerView={1.2}
          loop
          ref={swiperElRef}
        >
        <swiper-slide>
            <div>1</div>
        </swiper-slide>
         <swiper-slide>
            <div>2</div>
        </swiper-slide>
     </swiper-container>
     </div>
  )
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `init="false"` as an attribute to prevent auto-initialization. You are already calling `initialize()` manually in your `useEffect`, so it will happen then, *after* properties are assigned)

```
<swiper-container
    style={{ width: "100%", paddingBlock: "1rem" }}
    spaceBetween={16}
    slidesPerView={1.2}
    loop
    init="false"
    ref={swiperElRef}
>
    <swiper-slide><div>1</div></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><div>2</div></swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```